# Rumbling noise that drives me crazy!

Tags: engine, noise, hyundai, accent

2006 Hyundai Accent 48,000 Miles. Makes this weird rumbling noise as I am coming to a stop (when braking) and stops as soon as the car is at a complete stop. It started off being a very rare occurrence when I got the car at 46,000 miles, now it is almost every time I drive. I do not believe it is the brakes (they seem to work fine) for the fact that when Reversing or in Park it will occasionally make the same noise. When I shift to Neutral it calms down quite a bit. It happens much more often when coming to a stop. It drives me insane! I believe you can only hear it from inside the car. Want to take it to a mechanic but not too sure if they will figure it out. Any ideas or thoughts of what it could be? HELP! I know next to nothing about cars and self diagnosing seems impossible.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You need to eliminate the brakes as the source of the noise. If it is happening when you step on the brakes, it seems logical to me that's where the noise is coming from. Check them to ensure there is actually meat on the bones (friction material on the pads). Check both the inside and outside pads for both sides of the vehicle.

Comment: There are numerous things which could cause this sound. Your best bet is to take it to a mechanic for an inspection. This website will have far less luck determining what is wrong with the information you have provided.

Comment: Note that even when your brakes are down to metal scraping on metal, it might feel like they are working fine except for the noise.  I had a newer model car and I started hearing a grinding noise, and I new it _couldn't_ be the brakes because it just didn't have that many miles, and it stopped fine.  Turned out the rear brakes were down to the metal - making a grinding sound.